# File saving on HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, signalr

I'm trying to develop `SignalR` `JavaScript` client (plain `HTML` page, which gets live updates from my SignalR backend using JavaScript), and I'm struggling with file pushing problem.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Backend does some work and saves results to *.zip file on server, pushes this file to client, `HTML` page offers operator to save the file. Below there is a `C#` backend code doing zipping and push.

```
private void CreateZip()
        {
            if (SdkHub.RR.XMLResults && SdkHub.RR.SaveImages)
            {
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    var mstream = new MemoryStream();
                    mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    zip.AddDirectory(mydir);
                    zip.Save(mstream);
                    mstream.Position = 0;
                    Clients.All.downloadResult(mstream.ToArray(), myName+".zip");
                }
            }
        }
```

I've spent some time researching "saving files with JavaScript" and found a solution [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), which allows to save generated files. My `JavaScript` code:

```
downloadResult: function (result, name) {
            try {
                var blob = new Blob(result, { type: "application/zip" });
                saveAs(blob, name);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

I've figured out, that I `SignalR` converts `byte[]` to `base64 string`, so I've made a little update to my `C#`:

```
 var intArray = mstream.ToArray().Select(b => (int)b).ToArray();
 Clients.All.downloadResult(intArray, myName+".zip");
```

While debugging, I see, that received `result` parameter in `JavaScript` is an array, equal to `byte[]` array in `C#`, and zip file saving is issued, but unfortunately, it's invalid. When I open it using `Notepad++`, I see my array `8513115 ...`

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe there are other solutions to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

**Update** Screenshot from FireBug debugger

[image: Screenshot from FireBug debugger]

Comment: can you try constructing the blob using type: 'application/octet-binary'

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this, but I've already tried.

Comment: Also let me know the value of result.constructor using the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Uinit8Array like:

```
downloadResult: function (result, name) {
  try {
    var u8 = new Uint8Array(result.length);
    for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) u8[i] = result[i];

      var blob = new Blob(u8, { type: 'application/octet-binary' });
      saveAs(blob, name);
  } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: It WORKS!!! But with one minor edit: `new Blob([u8], { type: 'application/octet-binary' })`

Comment: Oh, yes. I missed it! Congrats!